# Mapping Soil Sealing and Water Bodies

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, imagery, digital-image-processing

I am asked which bands of Landsat 9 (or 8) is best for mapping soil surface sealing and water bodies at higher resolution. The band available in Landsat 9 is as shown:-
[image]

From above band name; which band is suitable for mapping soil sealing and waterbodies from Landsat 9. Is that the band 2, band 6, band 7, band10 & band 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For water bodies try this general formula (normalized difference water index):

> NDWI  = ( (green-NIR) / (green+NIR) + (green-SWIR1) / (green+SWIR1) ) / 2

Landsat 8, 9:

> NDWI  = ((3-5) / (3+5) + (3-6) / (3+6) ) / 2

Landsat 7, 4-5 (TM):

> NDWI  = ((2-4) / (2+4) + (2-5) / (2+5) ) / 2

Values from 0.1 to 1 are water. Clouds and shadows need to be masked before processing, as with this index they are incorrectly detected as water.